# I need my nav menu to be fluid

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a nav bar in a div and I need the nav bar to be fluid. The table that it is in is based on percentage (100%) with a min width of 800px. What I think I need is for the images to be resizable based on the main container size. Each image (home, faq, testimonials...). I want to the image width and height to shrink when the window is resized down to the smallest (800px) so that it will all still fit in one line).

```
#nav-container {
height: 80px;
padding-left:10px;
overflow:auto;
}

ul#nav {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
}
ul#nav li a {
background-position: left top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: block;
text-indent: -9000px;
position: absolute;
}
ul#nav:hover li a{
background-position: left bottom;
}
ul#nav li a:hover{
background-position: left center;
}
ul#nav li a span{
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: none;
position: absolute;
}
ul#nav li a:hover span{
display: block;
}
ul#nav li a.home {
background-image: url(../images/home.gif);
height: 37px;
width: 118px;
top: 10px;
left: 0%;
}
ul#nav a.custom{
background-image: url(../images/home.gif);
height: 37px;
width: 118px;
top: 10px;
left: 13%;

}
ul#nav a.faq{
background-image: url(../images/home.gif);
height: 37px;
width: 118px;
top: 10px;
left: 26%;
}

ul#nav a.testimonails{
background-image: url(../images/home.gif);
height: 37px;
width: 118px;
top: 10px;
left: 40% ;
}
```

By giving the "left" a percentage instead of a  the distances between the buttons will change when the window is resized. However, I need to have a minimum distance between the buttons so that when the window goes to its smallest (800px) there is still a distance between the buttons, but when the window is maximized the distance isn't too great.

Comment: can you provide HTML that takes this style ?

Comment: Any way, Try out similar code as here http://addyosmani.com/resources/fluid-menu/fluid-menu.html

Answer (score 0):

You can set the min-width/min-height and max-width/max-height of elements in CSS.

[W3schools - CSS Dimension](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dimension.asp)

eg:

```
img
{
min-width:150px;
}
```

You could try using padding or margins to maintain distance between buttons, rather than using 'left'.

[CSS Margins and Padding](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)

Please provide a live demo for a more specific solution. I recommend using a service such as [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/).

I hope this helps.